# Using PyQGIS to append index to attribute table

Tags: pyqgis

How can I add a new column to an attribute table that just numbers each row 1-*n* with Python in QGIS?

Normally I just grab the code from the log history in QGIS, but there's no output for field calculator.

Better yet, does the attribute table an invisible, implicit index, such that I can access row numbers without having to add a field for it in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, actually there is an internal index for each feature that you can access easily in PyQGIS:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    print (feat.id())
```

The index starts at 0.